# Jooq - Join tables and map to another pojo

Tags: java, jooq

I have this classes:

```
class Student {
    String student_id;
    String name;
    List<GradeValue> grades;
}


class Grades {
    String id;
    String student_id;
    Long grade_value;
}


class GradeValue {
    Long grade_value;
}
```

I'm trying to use JOOQ to make a query that returns all students with all the grade values.

For this to happen I have to join the student and grades tables but then I should convert the grade to a grade value and I'm not sure how to do this.

```
List<Student> students = dsl.select(jsonObject(
    jsonEntry("id", STUDENT.STUDENT_ID),
    jsonEntry("name", STUDENT.NAME),
    jsonEntry("grades", field(
        select(jsonbObjectAgg(GRADES.GRADE_VALUE))
        .from(GRADES)
        .where(GRADES.STUDENT_ID.eq(STUDENT.STUDENT_ID))
    ))
)).from(STUDENT)
.fetchInto(Student.class);
```

Gives me this error:

> Caused by:
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot
> deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList<GradeValue>` out of
> START_OBJECT token  at [Source: (String)"{"id" : "1", "name" : "test",
> "grades" : {"grade_value": 10}}"; line: 1, column: 99]

Any ideias?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There are numerous problems with your code snippet:

#### Using `jsonArrayAgg()` instead of `jsonbObjectAgg()`

You didn't want to aggregate your grades into an object, I think, but into an array? Use [`jsonArrayAgg()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#jsonArrayAgg(org.jooq.Field)), instead. See these manual sections for details:

- https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/aggregate-functions/json-arrayagg-function/
- https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/aggregate-functions/json-objectagg-function/

Also, I suggest deciding for either using `JSON` or `JSONB` methods, not to mix them. But the way you wrote the query, that works for

```java
class Student {
    String student_id;
    String name;
    List<Long> grades;
}
```

Since you're wrapping the grade in another class, you have to reflect that as well in your generated JSON structure:

```java
List<Student> students = dsl.select(jsonObject(
    key("student_id").value(STUDENT.STUDENT_ID),
    key("name").value(STUDENT.NAME),
    key("grades").value(field(
        // See fix here
        select(jsonArrayAgg(jsonObject(
            key("grade_value").value(GRADES.GRADE_VALUE)
        )))
        .from(GRADES)
        .where(GRADES.STUDENT_ID.eq(STUDENT.STUDENT_ID))
    ))
)).from(STUDENT)
.fetchInto(Student.class);
```

#### Fetching into `STUDENT.class`

Perhaps just a typo, but you wrote:

```java
.fetchInto(STUDENT.class)
```

You probably meant to write:

```java
.fetchInto(Student.class)
```

#### Projecting the right attribute names

Your `Student` class has a `student_id` attribute, but you're projecting `id`:

```java
jsonEntry("id", STUDENT.STUDENT_ID)
```

Better rename that attribute to `id` also, or project `"student_id"`

#### Aggregating empty sets

Note that `JSON_ARRAYAGG()` aggregates empty sets into `NULL`, not into an empty `[]`. [If that's a problem, use `COALESCE()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67932476/521799)

Comment: @fitameh795: I don't know what possible new issue you might have encountered, but your using `jsonbObjectAgg()` doesn't make much sense. As you can see in your logs, you got a JSON object `{"grade_value": 10}` when you wanted to get a JSON array `[10]`. I'll be happy to walk you through any possible further issues, but I'll need a bit more information than "this doesn't work"...

Comment: @fitameh795: OK, I spotted it. See updated answer.